# How to evaluate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2(x-\tanh x)}{\sinh x \tanh^2x} \ \text dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\left[\,x - \tanh\left(\,x\,\right)\,\right]}
{\sinh\left(\,x\,\right)\tanh^{2}\left(\,x\,\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
I know that the answer is $\pi^{2}/4$.

I tried to change $\sinh\left(\,x\,\right)$ and $\tanh\left(\,x\,\right)$ to series but it's hard.  I hope to give me full answers with different methods.

Comment: Please type out our question using Jax instead of posting a picture. [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help you.

Comment: I will learn but I find it very hard

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{1}{4} \left(2+\pi ^2-2 \log (4)\right)$$

Comment: converting the integrand into the exponential form we get $$\frac{4 e^x \left(e^{2 x}+1\right) \left(e^{2 x} (x-1)+x+1\right)}{\left(e^{2
   x}-1\right)^3}$$ i hope this will help you

Comment: this is not true, the word always is at the wrong place, naturely we use mathematica here to find a faster way to solve problems

Comment: @tilper That link agrees with Dr. Sonnhard Graubner...

Comment: @lioness99a, for me it does now too.  But earlier it said $\approx 2.4674$.  I blame my standard computation time being exceeded.  (*eye-roll*)

Comment: Eye rolling at WA, not you.

Comment: Bleh, I highly recommend against finding the anti-derivative by hand T_T  But its doable... just let $u=e^x$ and perform PFD...

Comment: the value you put is equal to approximately 2.274 but the answer approximation is 2.4674?????

Comment: One could note the integral is symmetric about zero and attempt some complex analysis.

Comment: @tilper The $\underline{correct\ answer}$ is $\pi^{2}/4$. $Mathematica$ has some problem with this integral. I even checked it numerically. See my answer below.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The $\underline{correct\ answer}$ is $\pi^{2}/4$. $Mathematica$ has some problem with this integral. I even checked it numerically. See my answer below.

Comment: @FelixMarin, interesting.  WA actually gave me the correct answer first.  Now that I'm checking at home, even Maple Version 10 Classic Worksheet says $\pi^2/4$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that:

$$\int\frac{\tanh(x)}{\sinh(x)\tanh^2(x)}~\mathrm dx=-\operatorname{csch}(x)+c$$

$$\begin{align}\int\frac x{\sinh(x)\tanh^2(x)}~\mathrm dx&=2\int\frac{(u+u^{-1})^2}{(u-u^{-1})^3}\frac{\ln(u)}u~\mathrm du\\&=2\int\frac{(u^2+1)^2}{(u^2-1)^3}\ln(u)~\mathrm du\end{align}$$

By PFD,

$$\frac{32}{(x^2-1)^3}=\frac2{(x-1)^3}-\frac3{(x-1)^2}+\frac3{x-1}-\frac3{x+1}-\frac3{(x+1)^2}-\frac2{(x+1)^3}$$

Each may then be handled through a combination of integration by parts, letting $t=u\pm1$, and polylogarithms.  For example,

$$\begin{align}\int\frac{(u^2+1)^2}{(u-1)^3}\ln(u)~\mathrm du&=\int\frac{t^4+4t^3+8t^2+8t+4}{t^3}\ln(1+t)~\mathrm dt\\&=\int t\ln(1+t)+4\ln(1+t)+8\frac{\ln(1+t)}t+8\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t^2}+4\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t^3}~\mathrm dt\\&=\frac12t^2\ln(1+t)+4t\ln(1+t)-\frac12\ln(1+t)-8\frac{\ln(1+t)}t\\&\phantom{=}-4\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t^2}+4\ln(t)-\frac14t^2-\frac72t-\frac4t-8\operatorname{Li}_2(-t)+C\end{align}$$

(Dear lord, tell me I didn't do that wrong)

We may proceed with all the rest to finally conclude that

$$\int\frac{2(x-\tanh(x))}{\sinh(x)\tanh^2(x)}~\mathrm dx=\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{-x})-\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{-x})+x\ln(1-e^{-x})-x\ln(1+e^{-x})\\+\frac12\tanh(x/2)-\frac12\coth(x/2)-\frac14x\operatorname{csch}^2(x/2)+2\operatorname{csch}(x)-\frac14x\operatorname{sech}^2(x/2)+C$$

[(if this one's wrong, I'm blaming it on WA)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+2(x-tanh(x))%2F(sinh(x)tanh(x)%5E2))

And by substituting in the bounds,

> $$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{2(x-\tanh(x))}{\sinh(x)\tanh^2(x)}~\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi^2}4$$

Comment: Yup, just checked, and indeed, $\frac{\pi^2}4$ should be the correct result...

Comment: It's amusing the integral is reduced to the simple one $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \sinh\left(\,x\,\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x$. Indeed, I was surprised.

Comment: Indeed it is.  :-)  Sometimes these integrals need the right touch of magic to work out.

Comment: $\Huge{\bullet\quad\bullet \atop {\mid \atop \smile}}$

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}
{2\bracks{x - \tanh\pars{x}} \over \sinh\pars{x}\tanh^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
=
\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{2x\cosh^{2}\pars{x} \over \sinh^{3}\pars{x}} - {2 \over x^{2}}}\,\dd x\ +\ 2\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over x^{2}} - {\cosh\pars{x} \over \sinh^{2}\pars{x}}}\,\dd x}^{\ds{=\ 0}}
\end{align}
The second integral is trivially evaluated. Indeed,
[@Simply Beautiful Art already pointed out in his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2321076/85343) that the second integral involves
$\ds{\dd\bracks{\mrm{csch}\pars{x}}/\dd x = -\cosh\pars{x}/\sinh^{2}\pars{x}}$.

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}
{2\bracks{x - \tanh\pars{x}} \over \sinh\pars{x}\tanh^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\braces{%
-\int_{x = \epsilon}^{x \to \infty}x\cosh\pars{x}\,
\dd\bracks{1 \over \sinh^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x - {2 \over \epsilon}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\braces{%
{\epsilon\cosh\pars{\epsilon} \over \sinh^{2}\pars{\epsilon}} + \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}
{1 \over \sinh^{2}\pars{x}}\bracks{\cosh\pars{x} + x\sinh\pars{x}}\,\dd x -
{2 \over \epsilon}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
{\epsilon\cosh\pars{\epsilon} \over \sinh^{2}\pars{\epsilon}}  + {1 \over \sinh\pars{\epsilon}} + \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}{x \over \sinh\pars{x}}\,\dd x -
{2 \over \epsilon}} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \sinh\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\expo{-x} \over 1 - \expo{2x}}\,\dd x =
2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}x\expo{-\pars{2n + 1}x}\,\dd x =
2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}} =
2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}} -
2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{3 \over 2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}} =
{3 \over 2}\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} = \bbx{\pi^{2} \over 4}
\end{align}